# Bug when trying to download reports from shiny app locally

Tags: r, shiny, download, r-markdown, knitr

I have the shiny app below which generates and downloads reports in pdf and word format. To run this you need to save those 2 rmd files found [here](https://github.com/jienagu/noteMD_shiny_app) in the same folder and also install [tinytex](https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging). The issue is that while the files should be downloaded normally, this actually happens when the app is open in browser. When I run it locally the pdf just opens the file and the doc need to be renamed and the click 'Save' to get it. Why does this happen?

```
library(shiny)
# devtools::install_github("jienagu/noteMD")
library(noteMD)
library(knitr)  
library(rmarkdown)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton('describe_download',"Download Report",class="butt" ),br(),
      tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:#230682;} .butt{color: #e6ebef;}")),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'Word'),
                   inline = TRUE)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               helpText("Note: Any comments made in the box will be printed if you download the summary report.") ),
        column(12,
               tags$textarea(
                 "Please using any **markdown** syntax!",
                 id    = 'markdowninput',
                 rows  = 3,
                 style = 'width:100%;')) ),
      helpText("Preview:"),
      htmlOutput('htmlmarkdown')

    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {


  output$htmlmarkdown = reactive({
    note_in_html(input$markdowninput)
  })

  output$describe_download = downloadHandler(
    filename<- function(){
      paste("Summary",Sys.Date(),switch(
        input$format, PDF = '.pdf', Word = '.docx'
      ),sep = "")
    },

    content = function(file) {
      if (input$format=="PDF"){
        #### Progressing indicator
        withProgress(message = 'Download in progress',
                     detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                       for (i in 1:15) {
                         incProgress(1/15)
                         Sys.sleep(0.01)
                       }

                       ## End of progression
                       src <- normalizePath('summary_report.Rmd')

                       # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
                       # permission to the current working directory
                       owd <- setwd(tempdir())
                       on.exit(setwd(owd))
                       file.copy(src, 'summary_report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

                       library(rmarkdown)
                       out <- render('summary_report.Rmd', pdf_document())
                       file.rename(out, file)

                     })
        ### below is the end of pdf content
      }else{
        withProgress(message = 'Download in progress',
                     detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                       for (i in 1:15) {
                         incProgress(1/15)
                         Sys.sleep(0.01)
                       }

                       ## End of progression
                       src <- normalizePath('summary_report_word.Rmd')

                       # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
                       # permission to the current working directory
                       owd <- setwd(tempdir())
                       on.exit(setwd(owd))
                       file.copy(src, 'summary_report_word.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

                       library(rmarkdown)
                       out <- render('summary_report_word.Rmd', word_document())
                       file.rename(out, file)
                     })
      }

    })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```